# I have a valid Facebook API Access Token, but it returns as Invalid/Non-Active: oAuthException

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I send an access token in, that is valid by the Facebook Access Token Debugger, but it still says that it isn't an active/is an invalid access token

I have tried putting the access token through the debugger: Came up as active

```
var access_token = pathname.match(/\#(?:access_token)\=([\S\s]*?)\&/)[1];
$.ajax({
  url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me?name?access_token=" + access_token,
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    //Would want to do stuff with the Return data
  },
  error: function(response) {
    $("#nameField").html("<li class='dataField' id='nameField'>The response could not locate the data source</li>")
  }
});
```

I would want it to return JSON data/Single JSON entry. Ends up showing:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "BdmIzcoyALS"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the answer:

It was the fact that I was using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?name?access_token=
```

When I should have used:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?name&access_token=
```